# Если radio, checkbox не нажаты то функция не будет работать

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать так что бы результат не выводился пока не нажаты checkbox или radio. И это нужно сделать для всех элементов страницы.

```js
var rez=0,
d=document;
function v3(){
  for(i=0; i<d.getElementsByName("q3").length; i++){

      if(d.getElementsByName("q3")[i].checked) {

        if(i==0){rez+=2;}
        if(i==2){rez+=2;}
        if(i==3){rez+=1;}
      }

  }
alert(rez);

}
```

```html
<div id="v3" class="qdiv">
          <p class="quest">Для облика древнейшего человека характерны:</p><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="1" />выступающие челюсти</label><br><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="2" />прямая походка</label><br><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="3" />прыгающая походка</label><br><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="4" />руки, свисающие ниже колен</label><br><br>
          <a href="#" onclick="v3()" class="btnflip">
             ответить
          </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: А можно задачу узнать? 
Довольно странная реализация неизвестно чего :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!rez) return false;
```

```js
var rez = 0,
  d = document;
function v3(){
  for(i = 0; i < d.getElementsByName("q3").length; i++){
      if(d.getElementsByName("q3")[i].checked) {
        if(i == 0) rez += 2;
        if(i == 2) rez += 2;
        if(i == 3) rez += 1;
      }
  }
  if (!rez) return false;
  alert(rez);
}
```

```html
<div id="v3" class="qdiv">
  <p class="quest">Для облика древнейшего человека характерны:</p><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="1" />выступающие челюсти</label><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="2" />прямая походка</label><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="3" />прыгающая походка</label><br><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="q3" value="4" />руки, свисающие ниже колен</label><br><br>
  <a href="#" onclick="v3()" class="btnflip">
     ответить
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не то нужно, надо что бы  какой либо checkbox был нажат, не важно правильный или нет.

Comment: @Павел Рыбакин Шта?